# casperjs button click doesn't navigate to next page

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a page that contains the HTML form with javascript setup like if you click on a button with someid, the form gets submitted. I verified this by firing this in browser console:

document.getElementById("arcotsubmit").click()

As soon as it gets fired, the url changes and form gets submitted.

Now i tried to replicate this with casper.js:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({});


casper.start('https://cib.icicibank.com/corp/BANKAWAY?Action.CorpUser.Init1.001=Y&AppSignonBankId=ICI&AppType=corporate', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function(){

    this.click("#arcotsubmit");

});

casper.then(function(){

    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl())
});

casper.run();
```

It stays on the same URL and downloads the same page. I want to download the html that appears after the button gets clicked by casper. The URL is live and can be tested directly.

My point is if i can use this command in browser console

```
document.getElementById("arcotsubmit").click()
```

and make it redirect, why i am unable to do it with
this.click("#arcotsubmit") in casperjs?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, because I am having the same issue? And, I am using straight PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

It is **submit** instead **click** for redirecting. The default event for *input[type=image]* is **submit** so that try this:

```
casper.test.begin('Test page.', 2, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(
        'https://cib.icicibank.com/corp/BANKAWAY?Action.CorpUser.Init1.001=Y&AppSignonBankId=ICI&AppType=corporate',
        function() {
            this.echo(this.getTitle());
            test.assertUrlMatch(/BANKAWAY?/, 'Current location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        }
    );

    casper.then(function(){
        this.fill('#rt', {}, true);
        this.wait(2000, function() {
            test.assertUrlMatch(/BANKAWAY;/, 'New location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

It will be passed.
[Test Result Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcChN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Possible quick fix.  If Casper's click isn't working, but your code works in console of the browser, try using Casper's [evaluate](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) function.

```
casper.then(function() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("arcotsubmit").click();
  });
});
```